# move selectionsColumn in magento 2 to the left of admin grid

Tags: magento2, grid

I have added selectionsColumn in admingrid but it appear in the right of the table. I want to move it to left of the table. how can I do that? Here is column section of my listing.xml

```
<!-- Column -->
  <columns name="lern_carrier_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">carrier_id</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="carrier_id">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
          <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
          <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </column>
  </columns>
```

Comment: Please add admin screenshot

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/6rwpbzku5/ @AnkitShah

Comment: @Aaron is correct just drag & drop columns & it will work :)

Comment: i can't drag the checkbox column @AnkitShah

Comment: It's default feature. Check for other listings

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Step-1 :- Please comment all columns except of selectionsColumn(in uicomponent) & reload your admingrid first. So You'll get only checkbox column.
Step-2 :- Now uncomment all columns & reload the page and your problem will be solved :)
If not, then pls let me know. I'll try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drag and drop the column header into the position you want.

Comment: i can't drag the checkbox column

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop the column header.
I have tested and it's working. But Action column can not be dragged and dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment all columns except of selectionsColumn(in uicomponent) & reload your admingrid first. So You'll get only checkbox column. - **This solution didn't work on production, bacause usually you can't comment collums on production server.**

You can add draggable setting to drag and drop multiselection column

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <settings>
      <indexField>id</indexField>
      <draggable>true</draggable>
    </settings>
</selectionsColumn>
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-multiselectcolumn.html